# Cross platform GUI Programming with D

Tags: user-interface, cross-platform, d

I want to start programming with D.  I have a simple application in mind that needs a GUI but I want to make sure it's portable to Linux/Windows/Mac equally well and with minimal (no) change for each platform.

wxD is looking like the contender of choice because I know the wx toolkit already.

I see fltk4d as a contender and a (unfinished) wrapper around Qt.

Are there any other truly cross platform GUI toolkits for D that will go where I want with little effort and what would the the toolkit of choice for people here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[GtkD](http://www.dsource.org/projects/gtkd) should be a very good option for you as a stable Windows/Linux/Mac GUI toolkit.

[DWT](http://www.dsource.org/projects/dwt) was once considered the standard, it has its own newsgroup on the Digital Mars server and I think Walter Bright may have called it the standard too. I don't think it's completely working on Mac but this should change in the future.

[Here](http://www.prowiki.org/wiki4d/wiki.cgi?GuiLibraries) is a nice list of some other options but most have less active development and/or are not yet ready for production.

Comment: DTW was labeled the standard by Walter when it used Phobos, the current one runs on Tango and still has inherited the 'standard' label. It really doesn't mean anything. Progress has been made for the Mac side, but still not usable.

Answer (score 1):

I have not used any of D's GUI libraries, but I would go with wxD if I wanted to use one now. I would pick it because I think wxD would have the most native looking controls and is cross-platform. Especially since you already know wx, it looks like a good choice.

I'm actually writing a cross-platform GUI library, Dynamin, but I have not released it yet. It is not a port; ported libraries tend to not have as nice of APIs or take advantage of as many language features. But it is not far enough along to do more than simple programs. I also don't have a Mac backend or GTK theme yet.